# How can I remove/use the header bar with photonkit?

Tags: css, macos

I'm using photonkit.com to build an app, and this is happening:

[image: Double head bar issue screenshot]

As you can see, the header bar is ugly.
There aren't many examples on the web (none) and neither could find an issue on Github page.

Solutions may be:

- deactivate app header bar (then how do we handle the exit-minimize-maximize buttons?)
- Or making the color for the top bar to something else so it doesn't look double.

I'm asking in case the dev already has a solution.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Photon</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/photon.min.css">

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="js/menu.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="window">

        <header class="toolbar toolbar-header">
            <div class="toolbar-actions">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="icon icon-home"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="icon icon-folder"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn btn-default active">
                    <span class="icon icon-cloud"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="icon icon-popup"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="icon icon-shuffle"></span>
                  </button>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-default">
                  <span class="icon icon-home icon-text"></span>
                  Filters
                </button>

                <button class="btn btn-default btn-dropdown pull-right">
                  <span class="icon icon-megaphone"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Your app's content goes inside .window-content -->
        <div class="window-content">
            <div class="pane-group">
                <div class="pane pane-sm sidebar">
                    <nav class="nav-group">
                        <h5 class="nav-group-title">Favorites</h5>
                        <span class="nav-group-item">
                <span class="icon icon-home"></span> connors
                        </span>
                        <span class="nav-group-item active">
                <span class="icon icon-light-up"></span> Photon
                        </span>
                        <span class="nav-group-item">
                <span class="icon icon-download"></span> Downloads
                        </span>
                        <span class="nav-group-item">
                <span class="icon icon-folder"></span> Documents
                        </span>
                        <span class="nav-group-item">
                <span class="icon icon-window"></span> Applications
                        </span>
                        <span class="nav-group-item">
                <span class="icon icon-signal"></span> AirDrop
                        </span>
                        <span class="nav-group-item">
                <span class="icon icon-monitor"></span> Desktop
                        </span>
                    </nav>
                </div>

                <div class="pane">
                    <table class="table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Kind</th>
                                <th>Date Modified</th>
                                <th>Author</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>bars.scss</td>
                                <td>Document</td>
                                <td>Oct 13, 2015</td>
                                <td>connors</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>base.scss</td>
                                <td>Document</td>
                                <td>Oct 13, 2015</td>
                                <td>connors</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>button-groups.scss</td>
                                <td>Document</td>
                                <td>Oct 13, 2015</td>
                                <td>connors</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>buttons.scss</td>
                                <td>Document</td>
                                <td>Oct 13, 2015</td>
                                <td>connors</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>docs.scss</td>
                                <td>Document</td>
                                <td>Oct 13, 2015</td>
                                <td>connors</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>forms.scss</td>
                                <td>Document</td>
                                <td>Oct 13, 2015</td>
                                <td>connors</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>grid.scss</td>
                                <td>Document</td>
                                <td>Oct 13, 2015</td>
                                <td>connors</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>icons.scss</td>
                                <td>Document</td>
                                <td>Oct 13, 2015</td>
                                <td>connors</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>images.scss</td>
                                <td>Document</td>
                                <td>Oct 13, 2015</td>
                                <td>connors</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [electron docs][1], you can use this option on your app.js:

> On Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite and newer, there's an alternative way to specify a chromeless window. Instead of setting frame to false which disables both the titlebar and window controls, you may want to have the title bar hidden and your content extend to the full window size, yet still preserve the window controls ("traffic lights") for standard window actions. You can do so by specifying the new titleBarStyle option:

```
var win = new BrowserWindow({ 'titleBarStyle': 'hidden' });
```

That would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that he's using background-image with linear-gradient so you'll have to overwrite(`background-image: none`) those lines before you can use custom designs.

You can also comment those(under `.toolbar`) lines out in photon.(min.)css